# what is root? is it system app? and why it uses internet?

Tags: root-access, android-emulator

why there is a root that uses internet in my android smartphone?

what is root? is it system app? and why it uses internet?[image]

Comment: One should never be seeing an entry like this. Which Android phone, Android version are you using? From where did you take this screenshot? Do you have an app named root that is listed under Settings > Apps > All/System apps?

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, "root" is the name given to the super-user. It's kind of like the administrator in Windows, but far more powerful — root has permission to do *anything* on a Linux system.

Android is a Linux system, which means that it has a super-user called "root".

root (always spelled lowercase) is not an app. root is a user.

If you "root" a phone, what it really means is that you give yourself — and every app on the phone — the same powers as root.

You are advised **not** to root your phone, unless you are a power user who knows what you are doing, and you have good reason to do so. This is because root allows anything, making it easy to mess up your phone or to introduce dangerous malware.

Some apps on the Play Store require root to work. If you haven't rooted your phone, you can't use those apps.